# Intersection of Two Arrays II using C

Tags: arrays, c

Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection.

Example 1:

Input: nums1 = [1,2,2,1], nums2 = [2,2]
Output: [2,2]
Example 2:

Input: nums1 = [4,9,5], nums2 = [9,4,9,8,4]
Output: [4,9]
Note:

Each element in the result should appear as many times as it shows in both arrays.
The result can be in any order.
Follow up:

What if the given array is already sorted? How would you optimize your algorithm?
What if nums1's size is small compared to nums2's size? Which algorithm is better?
What if elements of nums2 are stored on disk, and the memory is limited such that you cannot load all elements into the memory at once?
**My Solution:**

```
int cmp(const void *a,const void *b){
    return *(const int *)a - *(const int *)b;
}

int min(int num1,int num2){
    if(num1<=num2){
        return num1;
    }
    else{
        return num2;
    }
}

/*
Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
*/
int* intersect(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size, int* returnSize){
    qsort(nums1,nums1Size,sizeof(int),cmp);
    qsort(nums2,nums2Size,sizeof(int),cmp);
    int minimum = min(nums1Size,nums2Size);
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*minimum);
    
    int i=0,j=0,index=0;
    while(i<nums1Size && j<nums2Size){
        if(nums1[i]<nums2[j]){
            i++;
        }
        else if(nums2[j]<nums1[i]){
            j++;
        }
        else if(nums1[i]==nums2[j]){
            arr[index]=nums1[i];
            printf("%d ", arr[index]);
            i++;j++;index++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<minimum;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

When I run the above code the output I get is **]**
although my logic is correct. the above printf statements give the correct answer as shown below:
[image: output on running the code]

Any idea what's the error in my code. I don't need any other approach for this. I only want you to help me with my code. Thank you in advance!
**I am using LeetCode.**

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. It just prints the result twice, once in `intersect`'s `while` loop and again in the `for` loop, below the `while`. Also, it is not printed in the expected format.

Simply remove the `printf` in the `while` loop, and instead of the `for` loop you have, use this one:

```c
printf("[");
for(i=0;i<minimum;i++){
    if (i < minimum-1){
        printf("%d,",arr[i]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
}
printf("]");
```

Comment: The printf statements I added are to check if my code functions properly. I am coding on leetcode so they have their main function defined already. All I have to do is return the array with duplicates and  printing the array is their job. In the image above in my question, You can see that in the section "Your answer", it prints ] this for my array. whereas the expected answer is [2,2]. Any idea why is this so?

Comment: sorry, did not know that. In that case, the problem is that you do not update the `returnSize` in your `intersect` function. Simply write `returnSize = index;` before `return arr;`